# Please review my logical data model

Tags: database-design

I have to design and implement a database on the study course. I want to make sure that my scheme is correct. I've created a model company and a system which needs a database.

A little background about the database: The database is designed for the company who test applications for external clients. Let's say that the company offers performing acceptance and compatibility testing services. The workflow of the company:

1. Seller (Client) requests for testing his application
2. The ticket is created
3. Ticket contains information about the application and what should be tested
4. Test Manager decides which Tester should test the application (ticket)
5. Tester reports defects to the application
6. When testing is done, tester set a result

Other businesses requirements:

1. Seller can requests for testing the application more than one time
2. Only one tester can test the application (ticket) in one iteration
3. History of testing should be collected and available

The updated model:
[image]

I'm not good into database designing, it's my first bigger project. So forgive me a basic mistakes :) If the diagram is not readable so I'd be glad to hear some advices how to make it pretty. Also, if someone see some weak points, please comment it.

Comment: By ambiguous I meant it wasn't clear which entity/attribute was the referring and which the referenced. The new diagram is much better. Comments withdrawn.

Comment: I'd suggest it should be `Languages --< apps_languages` rather than what's drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few general points.

Firstly, your diagram is a bit confusing! There are lines which merge into each other and the source and destination tables aren't clear.

Secondly (and this is a matter of opinion), you might want to use `<table_name>_id` as your `PRIMARY KEY` (e.g. `ticket_id`). It removes ambiguity, makes debugging easier and SQL easier to write and particularly read. My own personal convention is to use `lower_case_with_underscores_id` (and lower case for identifiers generally) and `UPPER CASE FOR SQL`. This makes code a pleasure to read and almost self-parsing.

Also, take a look [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/tracking_software_problems/index.htm), it's from [databaseanswers.org](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) which can be a good first port of call for database modelling projects! Try and make your diagram look a little bit more like that!

Finally, you can download [F/LOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) applications for bug-tracking - there's [more of them](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=list%20of%20bug%20tracking%20software&t=ffab&atb=v84-6&ia=web) than you can shake a [stick at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems)! Again, personal recommendation, you should look at [Fossil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_(software)) - it's by [D. Richard Hipp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._Richard_Hipp), the same guy who's given the world [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)!

I've watched some podcasts by him and he's impressive! At least take a look at his schema - you can be sure that thought went into it! It's BSD licenced, but I'm not sure if your professor/lecturer would be happy about you claiming his work as your own, but if you clearly refer to it, that should be OK! :-)

Be prepared to make a lot of changes - as [Helmuth Von Moltke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmuth_von_Moltke_the_Elder) said, "no plan survives contact with the enemy" - best of luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for a helpfully respond! I'll change these lines and use lowercases are you advised. Databaseanswers.org looks very good and I'll fix my scheme based on it. 

What can you say about AppPlatform, AppLang, AppAttach tables? Is it correct or should I use data dictionaries? My college friend said that it's not allowed to use tables like that. I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know whether the stackxechange's rules allow for editing the question and updating the scheme so I'll upload a new open as an answer. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, you can always edit your own question. Be sure and put `@Vérace` in a comment so that I see any edit to the question! If my answer was helpful, you can upvote it and/or mark it as correct!

Comment: please take a look at the updated scheme. Unfortunatly, I can't upvote because my rank is too low.

Comment: It looks good to me - but then, I haven't written any code to extract meaningful data from your schema - I presume that's part of your course work :-). You **will** find that you are trying to perform function A and that you'll need to  change table x. This will have an effect on function B (already working) and tables y and z... Also, you **could** store the data all in one table (**NOT ADVISED**) and use very complex app code to do virtually anything (see EAV)! The best solution (IMHO) is to put as much complexity into the db as possible - it's a database project - **use** the database! HTH.